# Why is my Grid Traveler Memoization still sticking?

Tags: c++11, runtime, dynamic-programming, unordered-map, memoization

I'm currently working on implementing memoization into the Grid Traveler problem. It looks like it should work, but it's still sticking on bigger cases like (18,18). Did I miss something, or are maps not the right choice for this kind of problem?

P.S. I'm still very new at working with maps.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <unordered_map>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    uint64_t gridTravMemo(int m, int n, unordered_map<string, uint64_t>grid)
    {
        string key;

        key = to_string(m) + "," + to_string(n);
        if (grid.count(key) > 0)
            return grid.at(key);
        if (m == 1 && n == 1)
            return 1;
        if (m == 0 || n == 0)
            return 0;

        grid[key] = gridTravMemo(m-1, n, grid) + gridTravMemo(m, n-1, grid);
        return grid.at(key);
    }

    int main()
    {
        unordered_map<string, uint64_t> gridMap;

        cout << gridTravMemo(1, 1, gridMap) << endl;
        cout << gridTravMemo(2, 2, gridMap) << endl;
        cout << gridTravMemo(3, 2, gridMap) << endl;
        cout << gridTravMemo(3, 3, gridMap) << endl;
        cout << gridTravMemo(18, 18, gridMap) << endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of memorized search is to optimize running time by returning any previous values that you have calculated. This way, instead of a brute force algorithm, you can reach a runtime of `O(N*M)`.

However, you are passing your `unordered_map<string, uint64_t>grid` as a parameter for your depth-first search.

You are calling `grid[key] = gridTravMemo(m-1, n, grid) + gridTravMemo(m, n-1, grid);` This means that your search is splitting into two branches. **However, the `grid` in these two branches are different.** This means that the same state can be visited in two separate branches, leading to a runtime more like `O(2^(N*M))`.

When you're testing an 18x18 grid, this definitely will not run quickly enough.

This is relatively easy to fix. Just declare `grid` as a global variable. This way its values can be used between different branches.

Try something like this:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <unordered_map>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    unordered_map<string, uint64_t> grid;

    uint64_t gridTravMemo(int m, int n)
    {
        string key;

        key = to_string(m) + "," + to_string(n);
        if (grid.count(key) > 0)
            return grid.at(key);
        if (m == 1 && n == 1)
            return 1;
        if (m == 0 || n == 0)
            return 0;

        grid[key] = gridTravMemo(m-1, n) + gridTravMemo(m, n-1);
        return grid.at(key);
    }

    int main()
    {

        cout << gridTravMemo(1, 1) << endl;
        grid.clear()
        cout << gridTravMemo(2, 2) << endl;
        grid.clear()
        cout << gridTravMemo(3, 2) << endl;
        grid.clear()
        cout << gridTravMemo(3, 3) << endl;
        grid.clear()
        cout << gridTravMemo(18, 18) << endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I was under the assumption though that storing the values of solved grids would reduce the time significantly and that the map remained the same throughout the execution. I see what you're saying though.